# Create Geometry from multiple paths

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have converted an image in to xaml using some tool and the output is

like this with multiple paths

```
        <Path Fill="#eb2028" Data="M 219,104 L 221,104 L 221,103........ />
        <Path Fill="#ffffff" Data="M 141,105 L 171,105 L 171,110......../>
        <Path Fill="#d4252c" Data="M 226,112 L 230,112 L 230,113 L 229......../>
```

How can I create a  single "Geometry" element joining all paths in xaml code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`DrawingGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Represents a collection of drawings that can be operated upon as a single drawing.

Example:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="ExampleImage">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 14.72,15.68L 12.38,15.68L 7.205,5.92L 7.11,5.92L 2.29,15.68L 0,15.68L 6.58,2.56L 7.595,2.56L 14.72,15.68 Z "/>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 21.585,25.6C 21.1017,25.6 20.69,25.4275 20.35,25.0825C 20.01,24.7375 19.84,24.3267 19.84,23.85C 19.84,23.37 20.01,22.955 20.35,22.605C 20.69,22.255 21.1017,22.08 21.585,22.08C 22.0783,22.08 22.4975,22.255 22.8425,22.605C 23.1875,22.955 23.36,23.37 23.36,23.85C 23.36,24.3267 23.1875,24.7375 22.8425,25.0825C 22.4975,25.4275 22.0783,25.6 21.585,25.6 Z "/>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 28.625,25.6C 28.1417,25.6 27.73,25.4275 27.39,25.0825C 27.05,24.7375 26.88,24.3267 26.88,23.85C 26.88,23.37 27.05,22.955 27.39,22.605C 27.73,22.255 28.1417,22.08 28.625,22.08C 29.1183,22.08 29.5375,22.255 29.8825,22.605C 30.2275,22.955 30.4,23.37 30.4,23.85C 30.4,24.3267 30.2275,24.7375 29.8825,25.0825C 29.5375,25.4275 29.1183,25.6 28.625,25.6 Z "/>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 35.665,25.6C 35.1817,25.6 34.77,25.4275 34.43,25.0825C 34.09,24.7375 33.92,24.3267 33.92,23.85C 33.92,23.37 34.09,22.955 34.43,22.605C 34.77,22.255 35.1817,22.08 35.665,22.08C 36.1583,22.08 36.5775,22.255 36.9225,22.605C 37.2675,22.955 37.44,23.37 37.44,23.85C 37.44,24.3267 37.2675,24.7375 36.9225,25.0825C 36.5775,25.4275 36.1583,25.6 35.665,25.6 Z "/>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 48.96,25.155L 48.96,28.48L 47.36,28.48L 47.36,25.28C 45.1267,25.28 43.3133,24.8217 41.92,23.905L 41.92,21.12C 42.5267,21.6633 43.3567,22.1192 44.41,22.4875C 45.4633,22.8558 46.4467,23.04 47.36,23.04L 47.36,15.14C 45.08,14.04 43.6033,13.0258 42.93,12.0975C 42.2567,11.1692 41.92,10.0717 41.92,8.805C 41.92,7.30167 42.4325,6.0025 43.4575,4.9075C 44.4825,3.8125 45.7833,3.15667 47.36,2.94L 47.36,9.53674e-007L 48.96,9.53674e-007L 48.96,2.88C 51.12,2.94333 52.6133,3.23333 53.44,3.75L 53.44,6.4C 52.3167,5.60667 50.8233,5.18 48.96,5.12L 48.96,13.24C 51.1733,14.27 52.6867,15.2658 53.5,16.2275C 54.3133,17.1892 54.72,18.2833 54.72,19.51C 54.72,20.9867 54.2117,22.2267 53.195,23.23C 52.1783,24.2333 50.7667,24.875 48.96,25.155 Z M 47.36,12.37L 47.36,5.215C 46.4733,5.38833 45.7717,5.76917 45.255,6.3575C 44.7383,6.94583 44.48,7.66 44.48,8.5C 44.48,9.38 44.6908,10.1017 45.1125,10.665C 45.5342,11.2283 46.2833,11.7967 47.36,12.37 Z M 48.96,15.945L 48.96,22.915C 51.0933,22.4817 52.16,21.4133 52.16,19.71C 52.16,18.29 51.0933,17.035 48.96,15.945 Z "/>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```